# Crystal Reports Considers Only First Row for Report Header

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Crystal Report Displays Report header only from the first row of result set (from sp).
If I added any field in Report header which is in second or consequent rows which is not displays in report.
Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you place fields in report header then only first row will be displayed... to get other rows aswell place the fields in detail section, which will read all rows.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand how sections work in crystal reports.

```
**Report Header** -> shows info one time but only on the first page of the report
**Page Header** -> shows same info per every report page
**Details** -> shows different info from the same field filing the space that other sections left
**Report Footer** -> shows info one time but only on the last page of the report
**Page Footer** -> shows same info per every report page
```

So in your case, you should place your fields on Details section, so they can show different values per iteration.